# Java : Regex expression for lastindexOf

Tags: java, regex

My sample code :

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Test {

    /**
     * @param args
     */

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        String str[] = {"A","B","C"};
        String s = "TEST FOR A STRING CONSTANT B. END.";
        int retIndex = -1;

        for (int i = 0, len = str.length; i < len; i++){ 
            //length-1 is because, we should not check the empty space unicode(\u0021)

            int index = s.lastIndexOf(str[i]);
            if(index>retIndex){
                retIndex = index;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("RETINDEX"+retIndex);

        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("A|B|C");
        Matcher m = pattern.matcher(s);

        while(m.find()){
            retIndex = m.start();
            System.out.println(m.group()+" : "+m.end()+" : "+m.start());
        }

        System.out.println("REGEX RETINDEX"+retIndex);
    }
}
```

And I got the output:

```
RETINDEX27
A : 10 : 9
C : 19 : 18
A : 24 : 23
B : 28 : 27
REGEX RETINDEX27
```

I want the max index output only. No need to execute the other three loops. How to change the above one for my need?. Exactly lastindexOf match with regularExpression.

Thanks

Comment: What is your expected output?

Answer (score 9):

You can find the last occurrence of a regex by writing a greedy match for everything before it, for example:

```
.*(A|B|C)
```

Given your test string the `.*` will match everything up to the last B, and you can get the B from the capturing group.

To access the capturing group use the methods that take an `int` argument:

```
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".*(A|B|C)");
    Matcher m = pattern.matcher(s);
    if (m.find()) {
        retIndex = m.start(1);
        System.out.println(m.group(1)+" : "+m.end(1)+" : "+m.start(1));
    }
```

Comment: Simple and elegant. (For safety, perhaps add a `(?s)` at the start, so even newlines will be matched by `.*`).

Comment: but it returns m.start() as 0. why?

Comment: The pattern as a whole matches the string from the beginning. You have to get the start of the capturing group to get the index of B: m.start(1)

Comment: pattern is match whole string, so m.start() is 0,  exp: "abccd", use ".*(c)" to match capturing group, so the first group is "abcc", first group's start() is 0, the second group is "c", index is 3.  as the same logic, "(c).*), first group is "ccd", first group's start() is 2, the second group is "c", index is 2.